# Disable upon condition custom toolbar button

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using custom toolbar buttons on my Telerik mvc grid.

For example:

```
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
          {
toolBar.Custom().Url("#").ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text).Text("send to web service").HtmlAttributes(new {@onclick = "SendReportConfirmationDialog()"});

})
```

But this control has no .hidden(true) or .enabled(false) property so i'm trying to disable this button with true or false based on certain boolean value.

Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such configuration. You can try to disable it with JavaScript when the Grid is loaded (OnLoad event)

```
$('.t-toolbar .t-button').addClass('t-state-disabled').click(function(){return false});
```

The above will disable all the buttons in the toolbar - to be more specific you can assign class to your command button via the HtmlAttributes method,

```
tb.Custom().Text("test").HtmlAttributes(new{ @class="myTbCommand"})
```

And Change the selector:

```
$('.myTbCommand').addClass('t-state-disabled').click(function(){return false});
```

Dunno if this helps, but I think there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution was quite simple:

Using if condition in the method chain based on the value from the controllers ViewBag. This works and no buttons appear in the custom toolbar.

```
 .ToolBar(toolBar =>
      {
          if (ViewBag.gridEditMode != false)
          {
              toolBar.Custom().Url("#").Text("Send").HtmlAttributes(new {@onclick = "SendXSD()"});
          }
      })
```